# When I had update Android Studio to 3.0.1, I am getting error like "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'values/dimens.xml'"

Tags: android, android-studio

I have updated my Android Studio to `3.0.1`. after starting Studio, I get a strange error. I searched whole day, but couldn't find any solution for this. I even uninstalled Studio twice without keeping the old settings, but still facing the same issue. Please help, if anyone has gone through same issue.

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':myProject:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
```

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'values/dimens.xml'

Comment: I think the bug is due to the project itself, not Android Studio 3.
Did you try to start a blank project with Android Studio 3 ?

Comment: please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031395/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformresourceswithmergejavaresfordebug

Comment: yes @PAD i created a blank project and it works, thats why i replaced my whole code with old backup copy then i get the same error

Comment: I guess it's due to some library dependencies. Could you copy/paste your gradle config file ?

Answer (score 0):

Other users have been faced to this kind of issue after an Android Studio update to version 3.
Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47167522/3649279) and let us know if it solved your problem.

Comment: ya i seen this but there are no duplicate files in my lib. i think duplicate files are somewhere else which i cant detect.