# Using a native library in Android project results in a build error

Tags: android, gradle, face-recognition

I'd like to use this [face recognition library](https://github.com/Qualeams/Android-Face-Recognition-with-Deep-Learning-Library) in my Android project, and so I've added the library in my `build.gradle`. But when I build the project, it throws this error:

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java3.so'
```

I've tried to add this to my `android {}` in the app's `build.gradle`:

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java3.so'
}
```

and changed `pickFirst` with `exclude`, but it still returns the same error when rebuilding.

I have read that to use a native library, one needs to create a `jni` folder and put the native library code there, is this correct? If so, which files do I need to put there? As far as I'm concerned, the library is written in Java and it is a valid Android library, just that it uses native methods.

UPDATE: I've know added `jni`, `libs` and `obj` from library folder like so:

[image]

and specified

```
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    jni.srcDirs = []
}
```

However there is still a similar error when building:

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java3.so'
```

Any solution?

Comment: You will find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44962630/1237175).

Comment: @AdnanIsmajli I made the changes, but still got the same error above.