# Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug FAILED

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working with react native and every time I build a new project it seems to work on my device , but whenever I try to restart it It is giving me 1 or more errors

I have tried looking for solutions on github but none of them are clear I will post the entire error message here.

react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 855 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
24 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 22 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.

  > Could not read path 'C:\REACT_NATIVE\AwesomeProject2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJniLibs\debug\0\lib\arm64-v8a'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 57s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.

  > Could not read path 'C:\REACT_NATIVE\AwesomeProject2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\mergeJniLibs\debug\0\lib\arm64-v8a'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 57s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:623:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:641:15)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\REACT_NATIVE\AwesomeProject2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:75:39)
at buildAndRun (C:\REACT_NATIVE\AwesomeProject2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:169:41)
at C:\REACT_NATIVE\AwesomeProject2\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:135:12
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\REACT_NATIVE\AwesomeProject2\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\cliEntry.js:160:7)
```

Answer (score 64):

Running the cleaning task solved the problem for me. In your project's android dir, run gradle wrapper with 'clean'

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

Then you can go back to project dir and try running again.

```
cd .. && react-native run-android
```

Comment: Worked for me, thankyou! That was driving me crazy.

Comment: Thanks, working for me. Except I had to run `gradlew clean` without the dot slash.

Comment: This will work but you need to clean every time you run or else it will fail again

Answer (score 14):

go to android/app/build.gradle add the following under android

```
android {
    ...
+   packagingOptions {
+       pickFirst '**/libjsc.so'
+       pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
+       pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
+       pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
+       pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
+       pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
+       pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'  
+   }
}
```

Running the cleaning task solved the problem for me. In your project's android dir, run gradle wrapper with 'clean'

`cd android && ./gradlew clean`

Then you can go back to project dir and try running again.

`cd .. && react-native run-android`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because after adding these code I can run the app without cleaning the gradlew.

Answer (score 2):

Clean project working for me

A react-native Project is about one XCode Project and one Android Project. (pure js code no need to do clean)

So what are you need would be

Clean XCode Project with

```
$ cd ios
$ xcodebuild clean
$ cd .. && react-native run-ios
```

And then clean Android Project with

```
$ cd android
$ ./gradlew clean
$ cd .. && react-native run-android
```

You can simply write a batch file for it.

Answer (score 2):

in my case in react-native app this error was beacause of rn-fetch-blob v0.12.0,
and it makes release apk crash too 
i do this:

```
npm uninstall rn-fetch-blob
npm i rn-fetch-blob@0.11.2
cd android && gradlew clean
cd..
react-native run-android
```

hope this help somebody <3

Answer (score 1):

Go to android/app/build.gradle and add the following thing under android:

```
android {
  packagingOptions {
      pickFirst '**/libjsc.so'

  }
}
```

Then run it again. If your using react native i suggest you to close npm console and run it again.

Answer (score 1):

AAR libraries were not linking to the Main application from Bridge Project.

Solution:

```
implementation files(‘libs/sdk-5.0.0.aar’)
```

Instead of

```
implementation(name:'sdk-5.0.0', ext:'aar')
```

I faced another issue related to AAR file import into the android project.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58602329/3197778

Answer (score 1):

go to android/app/build.grad

```
    ...
+   packagingOptions {
+       pickFirst '**/libjsc.so'
+       pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
+       pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
+       pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
+       pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
+       pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
+       pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'  
+   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to android/app/build.gradle and add the following thing under android:

```
packagingOptions {
   pickFirst 'lib/x86/libswscale.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/x86/libavcodec.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/x86/libavformat.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/x86/libavutil.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/x86/libfbjni.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libavutil.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libavcodec.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libswscale.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libavformat.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libfbjni.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libavcodec.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libavformat.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libavutil.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libswscale.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libfbjni.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libavutil.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libavformat.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libavcodec.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libswscale.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libfbjni.so'
   pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
```

}