# Flutter Project Hitting libflutter.so not found on Windows 11 Home

Tags: flutter, windows

Unable to launch flutter app on Windows 11 Home device. Even `flutter doctor -v` shows no error. Does this mean i have to get a Mac ?

Hitting the error during VS code run without debugging/Start debugging, I had tried multiple solutions from the internet yet still not able to launch.

Tried with following following combinations of abiFilters to launch also same issue

```
ndk { abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64' }
ndk { abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a' }
ndk { abiFilters 'x86_64' }
ndk { abiFilters 'arm64-v8a' }
ndk { abiFilters 'arm64-v7a' }
```

Tried the following mobile emulator type combination also hitting same problem.

```
API Level = API 28, API 29, API 30, API 31, API 32, API 33, API 34 
ABI = x86_64
Target = Android 9, 10, 11, 12, 12L, 13, 14 (Google APIs)
```

I tried Android 11 and Android 9 based on following also doesn't solve the problem
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#support_for_arm_binaries_on_android_9_and_11_system_images

Added following to build.gradle as well, also not working

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/*/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/*/libflutter.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libflutter.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libflutter.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libflutter.so'
}
```

Following are the error log and flutter doctor result

```
 √  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
E/FlutterLoader( 5926): Flutter initialization failed.
E/FlutterLoader( 5926): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:123)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:193)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterLoader.java:243)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineGroup.<init>(FlutterEngineGroup.java:63)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.setUpFlutterEngine(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:323)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onAttach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:188)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:634)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary(FlutterJNI.java:145)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java:191)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java:185)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/FlutterLoader( 5926):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
> ```

Make sure the Flutter SDK is correctly installed and that the `libflutter.so` file exists within the SDK directory.

Following suggestions from [`flutter/flutter` issue 73943](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73943), it would be better to make sure the application packages the necessary native libraries for the most common Android ABIs (`x86_64`, `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64-v8a`). Do [specify these ABIs within the `ndk` block](https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/android/project-setup), making sure that the build process knows which architectures to include.

```bash
Flutter App
    |
    --> libflutter.so (not found)
          |
          --> Emulator (x86_64/armeabi-v7a/arm64-v8a)
                |
                --> Android SDK (API Levels 28-34)
```

Also, the [`packagingOptions` block](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/PackagingOptions) should include only the required ABIs.
Note: as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71678290/6309), `pickFirst()` is deprecated in favor of `resources.pickFirsts()` or `jniLibs.pickFirsts.add()`.

Your `build.gradle` would be:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libflutter.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libflutter.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libflutter.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libflutter.so'
    }
    ...
}
```

Then:

```bash
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

Or, still from [issue 73943](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73943#issuecomment-1996576538):

> 1. Delete "~/.gradle/cache/" and "~/.gradle/wrapper/dist/" directory.
> 2. Press F5 start VSCode debugging then stop
> 3. Got "dlopen failed library libflutter.so not found" error
> 4. Delete "~/.gradle/" and "{projectFolder}/Android/.gradle/"
> 5. Press F5 and everything is fine again